# validation for model that can belong to either one or the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a token model that belongs to a user and a customer, but also a room.

So what I want to do is check the uniqueness of the user, with a scope being the room id.

I also want to check the uniqueness of the customer, with a scope of the room id.

The issue is that if the token is made for the customer, the user_id will be nil. The same if it belongs to the user, the customer will be nil.

So how can I check that the token belongs either to a user or a customer. Taken into account that several will be nil, that might cause an error as that would go against the validation I assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can suggest here, you should use polymorphic association instead of using two (user_id and customer_id) different column. You can go through with the following url:

```
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations
```

and your uniqueness must be, with a scope of the room id and polymorphic_type column.

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :accountable, polymorphic: true
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :accountable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :accountable
end
```

then you need to create two (accountable_id and accountable_type) column in room table. Also uniqueness scope is based accountable type as well

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope=>:room_id, :allow_nil=>true
validates_uniqueness_of :customer_id, :scope=>:room_id, :allow_nil=>true

validates_presence_of :user_id,:if=>Proc.new { |x| x.customer_id.nil? }
```